# Not able to type in Text Input in Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

## Not able to type in Text Input in Android.

While making an app in React Native I realized that there is a text input in which I am not able to type. This problem is happening with **Android** only for **IOS** it is working fine. And I have to mention that I am not using **Android Studio** so the is no *Manifest.xml*. Here is the code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {View,TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

    class Login extends React.Component(){
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          password: "",
        }
      }
      
      render(){
        return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
               placeholder="Password"
               placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)"
               caretHidden={false}
               maxLength={35}
               autoComplete={false}
               autoCorrect={false}
               style={styles.input}
               secureTextEntry={true}
               onChangeText={(val) => {
                 this.setState({
                   password: val,
                 });
               }}
               value={this.state.password}
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container:{
        flex: 1,
      },
      input:{
        backgroundColor: '#ccc',
        height: 50,
        width: 320,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        textAlign: 'left',
        marginTop: 25,

        flex: 0.2,

        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        fontWeight: "500",
        paddingLeft: 10,
        color: 'black',
       }
    })
```

Comment: Can you add a little more information? On Android, does the keyboard appear when the input is focused? Have you tried excluding the styles to test, in case there is some overlap or style issue?

Comment: @AleksandarZoric The keyboard doesn't appear.

Comment: Try comment out the styles and see if it opens then? Also try typing with the desktop/laptop keyboard incase you hidden the keyboard.  I don't know what styles.input looks like or the container styles.

Comment: This may help you too, see the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706889/react-native-android-textinput-fail-to-show-keyboard

Comment: Thanks, @AleksandarZoric for your great research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **@AleksandarZoric** thanks for your suggestion.

> So got the answer using **@AleksandarZoric**'s help.

Just have to comment out all the *flex* styles. If it works, uncomment the *flex* styles and just try to decrease the values and it will work.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.